# Filter Leaflet Markers Omivore CSV File with Checkbox or the like

Tags: csv, leaflet

I'm looking at how to filter with a checkbox, radio button or other selector based on a few columns in the CSV file. This file has all my points and displays on the map fine. My filtering is where I am struggling. I am looking for a better way than creating a separate static filter for each type of display.

I have csv file I am parsing with [Omnivore](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore).

I can filter like so:

```
var freeLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
        filter: function(layer) {
            if (layer.properties.icon == "free")
                return true;
        }
    });
    var feeLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
        filter: function(layer) {
            if (layer.properties.icon == "fee")
                return true;
        }
    });
```

Then load my layer via Omnivore:

```
var free = omnivore.csv('data/all.csv', null, freeLayer)...
var fee = omnivore.csv('data/all.csv', null, feeLayer)...
```

Add my layerGroup:

```
var groupedOverlays = {
            "Fee Type": {
                "<img src='images/fee.png' width='26' height='26'>&nbsp;FEE": fee,
                "<img src='images/free.png' width='26' height='26'>&nbsp;FREE": free
            }...
```

This works just fine, but if I want to filter on another column / property in my csv file, I need to write another L.geoJson filter.

How can I update the layer property to use two or three different selections at a time for example? If i had checkboxes for FREE and FEE and both showed, but both were coming from one L.geoJson filter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in creating one `L.geoJson` layer group per filter.

The main drawback is that you parse multiple times the same CSV file, which may give some performance issue if the file is quite big.

I do not think you can change Leaflet-omnivore behaviour to create several groups, but you can work on `L.geoJson` or alternative strategies.

A simple workaround would hence be to use the [`onEachFeature` option](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-oneachfeature) of the `L.geoJson` constructor to add the newly created features / markers into other groups (your actual overlays), depending on whatever filter you need. Then the `L.geoJson` that was used for Omnivore would not need to be added to map, it would act only as an intermediate container.

Alternative strategies would be based on replacing Leaflet-omnivore by independent libraries. For example a CSV parsing library (PapaParse…), then loop through each line and build the features / markers yourself, directly in appropriate overlay layer groups depending on your filters. This strategy is also quite easy to implement, as CSV has a simple structure (on the contrary of other formats like KML for example, where Leaflet-omnivore shines).